# Grails mail plugin delivery to console / log in development mode

Tags: email, grails, configuration, grails-plugin

I am using Grails with the [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail). In development mode I would like the mails my applications sends to be rendered (to catch bugs in the templates) but printed to the console.

The only option I found was

```
grails.mail.disabled=true
```

But, according to the [documentation](http://gpc.github.io/grails-mail/docs/guide/2.%20Configuration.html):

> this will treat any call to mailService.sendMail() as a no-op

which is not quite what I want, since I want developers to be able to click on our confirmation links (for which I need the mail output).

Is there a nice way to "deliver" the mails to the console? I am aware that I could override the to-field with another address, but I'd rather not involve our mailserver when testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own dummy implementation of `mailService` as a class in `src/groovy` and then put some conditional code in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` to define your dummy service only in development mode.  The very simplest I can think of would be

**src/groovy/com/example/DummyMailService.groovy**

```
package com.example
import org.springframework.mail.MailMessage

class DummyMailService {
  MailMessage sendMail(Closure callable) {
    callable.delegate = new CallPrinter()
    callable.call()
    return null
  }
}

class CallPrinter {
  def methodMissing(name, args) {
    println "${name}: ${args}"
  }
}
```

**grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy**

```
import grails.util.Environment

beans = {
  if(Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
    mailService(com.example.DummyMailService)
  }
}
```

Obviously you could be cleverer, e.g. using a logger rather than `println`, or switching the dummy service based on a config option rather than just the environment (so you can turn on mail in dev mode later on when you specifically want to test it).

If you want to be able to handle `body(view:'...', model:[:])` calls that render templates you could do that using the `groovyPageRenderer`:

```
class DummyMailService {
  def callPrinter

  MailMessage sendMail(Closure callable) {
    callable.delegate = callPrinter
    callable.call()
    return null
  }
}

class CallPrinter {
  def groovyPageRenderer

  def methodMissing(name, args) {
    println "${name}: ${args}"
  }

  void body(Map params) {
    methodMissing("body", groovyPageRenderer.render(params))
  }
}
```

and in `resources.groovy`

```
mailService(com.example.DummyMailService) {
  callPrinter = { com.example.CallPrinter p ->
    groovyPageRenderer = ref('groovyPageRenderer')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I tested your code, it threw an exception stating `No signature of method: my.package.CallPrinter.to()`. When I renamed `invokeMethod` to `methodMissing` it worked. I'm not the groovy metaprogramming guru, so I can't say which way is right. The only thing missing is rendering of templates, which I would need to see/click on the aforementioned confirmation links. I am leaving this question open a little longer in case anyone has another suggestion.

Comment: @msung I've added a possible option for rendering body templates.

Answer (score 1):

GreenMail plugin is the closest to what you'd like that I can think of (see the plugin [here](http://grails.org/plugin/greenmail)). It will render the emails in a web page (the plugin provides a controller), not sure if you could set up Log4j to log the email to the console...